# SimpleDateFormat not returning uppercase formatted date

Tags: android, date-format, simpledateformat

I am trying to use the class `SimpleFormattedDate` to obtain a custom formatted date in my `Android` app, but I wasn't able to find a pattern returning uppercase letters.

These are my lines of code:

```
Date today = new Date();

Locale loc = new Locale("it","IT");//Locale.ITALIAN
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, ''yy", loc);
String output = formatter.format(today);
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), output,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

but this is what I get in return:

```
ven, giu 26, '15
```

but I would like to obtain this instead:

```
Ven, 26 Giu 2015
```

Comment: Are month and day names normally written in uppercase in Italian?

Comment: You will need to capitalize the letters yourself. I would recommend splitting this out to multiple strings and capitalizing the first character yourself. You can then combine the strings in the correct order.

Comment: just use Locale.ENGLISH instead of Locale.ITALIAN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First your formatter should be:

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E , d MMM yyyy",loc);
```

The capitalazion rules for italian might be different, if you still want to change it one option is to use the wordutils from apache commons , add de dependency to your gradle.build

> compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'

and then just do:

```
output=WordUtils.capitalize(output);
Toast.makeText(this, output,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the strings that **SimpleDateFormat** outputs by setting the **DateFormatSymbols** it uses. The official tutorial includes an example of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormatSymbols.html)

Example from the tutorial, applied to the **short weekdays**:

```
String[] capitalDays = {
    "", "SUN", "MON",
    "TUE", "WED", "THU",
    "FRI", "SAT"
};
symbols = new DateFormatSymbols( new Locale("en", "US"));
symbols.setShortWeekdays(capitalDays);

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E", symbols);
result = formatter.format(new Date());
System.out.println("Today's day of the week: " + result);
```